# Creamer returns

Tags: coffee

I use Nestle Coffee-mate creamer. I have noticed when I fix my thermos to go, the creamer has no problem dissolving when I first fix them, but let's say after 5 hours when the coffee has gotten cold, the creamer clumps back up.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Hot liquids can hold more dissolved solids than cold liquids. I don't know for sure but that may be what is happening. It could also be the chemicals in that 'creamer' eventually coagulate over time. Read the ingredients list, there is likely little or any cream in that 'creamer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I substituted your question in a quick google search for "solution chilled why do powders reappear" - and after reading a couple of the posts, I found this [one](https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Demos%2C_Techniques%2C_and_Experiments/General_Lab_Techniques/Recrystallization_(Advantages)/Recrystallization) to be the most succinct answer.

In short, as the coffee is hot it allows for rapid dissolving of the creamer due to high levels of excess energy (which we perceive as heat). However, as it cools the energy levels to keep the creamer dissolved are no longer there and it begins to "clump back up".

Have a read and good luck - cooking is just tasty chemistry.

Comment: All good - took a whole 60 seconds.